# One-liner doesn't perform second action

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to implement this simple algorithm:

1. If there are no directory "Abc", then create it.
2. Despite of the existing or non-existing of Abc, echo me "Hello".

But for some reason, I see greeting only if Abc wasn't created yet.

```
if not exist "Abc" mkdir Abc & echo Hello
```

How I may fix it?

Comment: `(if not exist "Abc" mkdir "Abc") & echo Hello`

Comment: Yep, it's work. Actually this was the first answer I received, so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @aschipfl Sorry, seems I forgot to mention you in previous comment.

Comment: Seems somebody else was faster than me...

Comment: @aschipfl Hm, actually not) It was about 30 secs later)

Comment: Yes, aschipfl was probably 30 seconds ahead of me. He also had the good idea to quote the directory name to be created. It is always best to be explicit with quoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmd` is putting the & portion with the `mkdir`. If the directory is not created, the & portion is never executed.

```
(if not exist "Abc" mkdir Abc) & echo Hello
```